# PHP code for database returning false

Tags: php, json, database

I'm making an app that has to retrieve data to balance a plane. I've created PHP code to connect to a database that should pull a columns value from an ID number, but the code is not working and is giving me a false return. Can anyone identify the problem as I can't seem to find the problem.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "*****", "*****");

      $id = $_POST["ID"];
      $paxfwdcabin = $_POST["PAXFWDCABIN"];
      $paxmidcabin = $_POST["PAXMIDCABIN"];
      $paxaftcabin = $_POST["PAXAFTCABIN"];
      $forwardhold1 = $_POST["FORWARDHOLD1"];
      $forwardhold2 = $_POST["FORWARDHOLD2"];
      $afthold3 = $_POST["AFTHOLD3"];
      $childadjustments = $_POST["CHILDADJUSTMENTS"];

      $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM RyanAirCWBalance WHERE ID = ? ");
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $id);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statment, $id, $paxfwdcabin, $paxmidcabin, $paxaftcabin, $forwardhold1, $forwardhold2, $afthold3, $childadjustments);

      $response = array();
      $response["success"] = false;

      while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["ID"] = $id;
        $response["PAXFWDCABIN"] = $paxfwdcabin;
        $response["PAXMIDCABIN"] = $paxmidcabin;
        $response["PAXAFTCABIN"] = $paxaftcabin;
        $response["FORWARDHOLD1"] = $forwardhold1;
        $response["FORWARDHOLD2"] = $forwardhold2;
        $response["AFTHOLD3"] = $afthold3;
        $response["CHILDADJUSTMENTS"] = $childadjustments;
      }

      echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I expect the result to allow my application to pull the value using a number which is the ID number.

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly.

Comment: What have you already tried, or do you expect us to solve the problem?

Comment: @JohnConde ive checked multiple times and im still getting the same error which is a false value

Comment: And always check your php_error.log

Comment: @StimpsonCat i dont expect you to solve it, just to point me in a direction that will help me solve it on my own, maybe telling me where abouts the code is not working so i cant fix it

Comment: MySQL tends to fail silently, unless you check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: @StimpsonCat im using atom to code and i have tried a php debugger, online debuggers and also showing my lecturer. the debuggers cant give me an error and my lecturer said that i should do it myself as he dont know php.

Comment: Funny thing- I want to be lecturer for quantum physics ;)

Comment: @StimpsonCat i want to be a computer teacher for secondary school... but at this rate my skills are not good enough by the looks of it.

Comment: @StimpsonCat i believe ive fount the problem.. the query is wrong? i ran a query in sql and it gave me the response i wanted

Comment: I am not php expert, but if you have found the query is correct, then try to vardump your vars and figure out what is going wrong, when you extract the result and build the response.

Comment: Again, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your query and each step to make sure everything is working correctly. MySQL does not throw PHP errors, so unless you check, you won't know what's going wrong.

Comment: @StimpsonCat the only thing wich the query i fount is that i dont think it will work with the application. basically a user will input the value and it needs to show a certain value if that makes sense. i now know that the query is the part that isnt workin